# pgAdmin and multiple SQL queries

Tags: postgresql, transactions, pgadmin

I run multiple SQL queries from pgadmin such as

```
INSERT INTO db1 (name)
VALUES ('Joe');
INSERT INTO db1 (name)
VALUES ('Bob');
```

in a single query window.
It runs fine and I see both names in my table. However, they are part of the same transaction. Does pgadmin automatically add a BEGIN and COMMIT before and after my queries?
Thanks
Murthy

Comment: It's in the docs [Query execution](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.6/query_tool_toolbar.html#query-execution)

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is auto-commiting but how is it doing it. If I turn auto-commit OFF, then I know that it sends a BEGIN before the queries. Is there some other flag that is set? Thanks.

Comment: From [Query tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.6/query_tool.html): "If Auto-commit is off, the data changes are made as part of the ongoing transaction, if no transaction is ongoing a new one is initiated. The data changes are not committed to the database unless the transaction is committed."  Then back to my original link for the icons to select for commit or rollback.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense that when auto-commit is OFF, we have to manually commit. What I am wondering is: If auto-commit is ON, does pgAdmin wrap my two sql statements into a BEGIN/COMMIT ?

Comment: No, each statement is committed in its own transaction.  There is an implicit `BEGIN/COMMIT`. The best way to see what is happening is to `tail` the Postgres log file.

Comment: Hmmm...when I run a SELECT xmin, name FROM test1, I see that both the entries have the same transaction ID. So it seems that both the SQL statements are part of the same transaction.

Comment: Well there is no telling what `pgAdmin` is doing behind the scenes. That is why I suggested looking at the Postgres log. On the Postgres side of things `autocommit` does what I posted earlier; [Set autocommit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
--In psql
create table autocommit_test(id integer, fld_1 varchar);

\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
on

insert into autocommit_test values(1, 'one'); insert into autocommit_test values(2, 'two');
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1

insert into autocommit_test values(3, 'three'); insert into autocommit_test values('four', 'four');
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "four"
LINE 1: insert into autocommit_test values('four', 'four');

select xmin, * from autocommit_test ;
  xmin  | id | fld_1 
--------+----+-------
 400129 |  1 | one
 400130 |  2 | two
 400131 |  3 | three

\set AUTOCOMMIT off
\echo :AUTOCOMMIT
off

insert into autocommit_test values(4, 'four'); insert into autocommit_test values(5, 'five');
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
select xmin, * from autocommit_test ;
  xmin  | id | fld_1 
--------+----+-------
 400129 |  1 | one
 400130 |  2 | two
 400131 |  3 | three
 400132 |  4 | four
 400132 |  5 | five

--From another psql session

select xmin, * from autocommit_test ;
  xmin  | id | fld_1 
--------+----+-------
 400129 |  1 | one
 400130 |  2 | two
 400131 |  3 | three

--Commit in insert session
commit;

--Other session

select xmin, * from autocommit_test ;
  xmin  | id | fld_1 
--------+----+-------
 400129 |  1 | one
 400130 |  2 | two
 400131 |  3 | three
 400132 |  4 | four
 400132 |  5 | five
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense and that is the same behavior I see with psql. I need to look into how pgadmin is sending the two queries. Trying to get logging working.